# Can SwiftKey be moved to the system partition?

Tags: link2sd, system-apps, swiftkey

I want to move the [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) app from my standard user partition to the system partition (I have root). I am able to use Titanium Backup or Link2SD to turn an app into a system app, but anytime I try that with SwiftKey, it continuously force-closes. With most apps, if they start acting up right after changing them to system apps, you simply reboot and it works. However, rebooting doesn't solve the problem with SwiftKey.

I have also tried clearing cache and dalvik cache, but it seems like this particular app hates being a system app.

According to [this forum thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1730336), I need to move a library over to the system lib folder, but I don't see any library needing to be copied.

Reinstalling the app looks like it works, but it doesn't really. Because updates to system apps are not stored in the system partition, 'updating' the Swiftkey app makes the app work again because the main binary that is running is running from userland, not systemland. If I then use Titanium Backup or Link2SD to `Integrate` the update into the system partition, it starts crashing again.

Has anyone been able to successfully move the SwiftKey app into the system partition?

**Edit**: I have tried clearing the cache, clearing the data, uninstalling completely and reinstalling (then moving to system), and I even tried the same steps on another phone of the same model (Optimus V).

I have also tried manually copying the .apk file over instead of simply using Titanium Backup's or Link2SD's built-in mover. SwiftKey simply refuses to run properly if installed as a system app, but works just fine as a user app.

Answer (score 1):

First, go to to Root folder then go to "/data/data/.com.android.swiftkey" then copy the "lib" files to "//system/lib" and after that,
go to root then "//data/app" and copy the "swiftkey" apps file to //system/app and restart your phone.
After rebooting open titanium backup, find swiftkey and wipe data.
Done. It wont force close again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have root, then its a simple matter of remounting the system partition as read-write and try copying the swiftkey's apk into `/system/app`, then remount the system partition again, it will then appear as a system application.

Then on first run, it will re-create the libs etc in the respective `/data` partition.

Comment: I have been able to move other apps just fine. I have system mounted as read/write. I'm having trouble specifically with SwiftKey.

Comment: @dymutaos Did you try *Titanium Backup*'s functionality to "integrate" a system app? Not sure if that helps, it's just an idea.

Comment: I couldn't remember the terminology until you mentioned it. Yes, I tried that. I'll update my question to use the proper term.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble too. Do this:

- Cut `libswiftkeysdk-java-internal.so` lib file inside `/data/data/com.touchtype.swiftkey/lib` and paste it in `system/lib`.
- Then move the apk from `/data/app` to `/system/app` and change permissions to `-rw-r--r--`.
- Restart and wipe data of Swiftkey app. All done.

It works flawlessly for me.